# Docker Swarm: re-aply placement preference of a service after node going back alive

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, high-availability

Docker applies constraints strictly, while placement preferences is not strictly enforced.

Here is the strategy I want to apply for my service:

- 2 replicas
- when possible, only one instance per container (spread across node)

Here is an extract of my docker-compose file:

```
        deploy:
          placement:
            constraints:
              - node.role == worker
            preferences:
              - spread: node.id
          replicas: 2
```

Now a simple scenario:

- 2 worker nodes running
- I deploy the service : each node has 1 instance
- 1 node becomes offline : the remaining node has 2 instances: OK
- the node comes back online: one node has now 2 instances while the other doesn't have any

Is it possible to tell Docker to re-apply placement preferences **automatically**?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue long back & seems like it's still not fixed or a fix is not required since it hampers their pre-existing logics in some way.

Open case - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24103

Comment: Very good link
One quick and dirty workaround in this issue is to scale up and back down to have the result

Comment: To me it sounds like an overkill. These sort of features if required should arrive out of the box :-) .

Comment: that's what k8s folks says :)